# Family of coloring lines and their crossing points

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ red and $m$ blue lines in the plane be given and $nm$ points of the intersection of lines of different colors are marked. Assume a family of green lines crosses all the marked points but precisely one. Prove that the number of green lines is at least $n + m − 2$.

Comment: Shouldnt be nm green lines exactly??

Comment: can you prove it in the case where red lines are vertical and blue are horizontal?

Comment: See here! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271823/covering-all-except-one-of-the-purple-intersection-points-of-n-red-and-m-blu/271849#271849

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Thank you very much for the link. I really appreciate your help.